# What do "seureopgo", "eopji", and "danghaetgo" mean in a song?

Tags: translation, romanisation

1.seureopgo
2.eopji
3.danghaetgo

I put a song through a few layers of google translate but some korean romanization came through instead of hangul or english

Comment: Just to be clear: you are basically looking at the result of a game of telephone.  If the translator failed to translate such basic words, it's fair to assume that you have a soup of detached words and phrases that are only loosely related to the original text.  It can be a fun way to kill time but keep in mind that the difference could be huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. seureopgo

   - 서럽다(seureopda): to be sorrowful (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EC%84%9C%EB%9F%BD%EB%8B%A4)
   - 서럽고(seureopgo): changed form of `서럽다`. (=`서럽다 그리고(and)`)
2. eopji

   - 없지: doesn't exist
3. danghaetgo

   - 당하다(danghada): to suffer or undergo something (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EB%8B%B9%ED%95%98%EB%8B%A4)
   - 당했다(danghaetda): past tense of `당하다`
   - 당했고(danghaetgo): (=`당했다 그리고(and)`)

Comment: 많이 감사합니다.......